# How to Regex this text: 999999999 RT 0001

Tags: android, regex

I need a regex for this text: `9999999999 TQ 0001`
with following rules:

```
•   Positions 1 – 9 are numeric and identify the business
•   Positions 10 – 11 are one of the following codes
◦   RC – corporate income tax
◦   RM – import / export
◦   RP – payroll deductions
◦   RT – GST/HST
•   Positions 12 – 16 are the reference number
```

Could you please help me. Thank

Comment: And your input has `TQ` which is not covered in your rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `/\d{9}\sR[CMTP]\s\d{4}/`.